# Pandas Conditional Rolling Sum of Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have four columns in a data frame like so:

```
       A   B     C        D
75472  d1  x    -36.0   0.0
75555  d2  x    -38.0   0.0
75638  d3  x    -18.0   0.0
75721  d4  x    -18.0   1836.0
75804  d5  x    1151.0  0.0
75887  d6  x    734.0   0.0
75970  d7  x    -723.0  0.0
```

And I want to conditionally sum `D` by:

- D has a value, then D
- Else, take value from previous row for D plus C

So for above, D would be `[-36, -74, -92, 1836, 2987, 3721, 2998]`.

I've been able to do this successfully with a for loop

```
for i, row in me.iterrows():
    try:
        if row['D'] > 0:
            step1 = me.loc[(me['B'] == row['B']) & (me['A'] == row['A']), 'output'].iloc[0]
            me_copy.iloc[i, me_copy.columns.get_loc('output')] = step1
        else:
            step1 = me.loc[(me['B'] == row['B']) & (me['A'] == (row['A'] - pd.DateOffset(days=1))), 'step1'].iloc[0]
            receipts_adjustments_sales = me.loc[(me['B'] == row['B']) & (me['A'] == row['A']), 'C'].iloc[0]
            me_copy.iloc[i, me_copy.columns.get_loc('output')] = step1 + receipts_adjustments_sales
    except:
        me_copy.iloc[i, me_copy.columns.get_loc('output')] = 0
```

But the for loop is obviously really expensive, anti-pattern and basically doesn't run over my whole data frame. I'm trying to copy an excel function here that has basically been written over a panel of data, and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this with:

- `pd.Series.shift()`
- `pd.Series.rolling()`
- Simply calculating different column values

I was attempting to do it with `shift()` for a while, but I realized that I kept having to make a separate column for each row, and that's why I went with a for loop.

**Generalized to Groups**

```
df.loc[:, 'A_group'] = df.groupby(['A'])[df['D'] != 0].cumsum()
df.loc[:, 'E'] = df['D'].mask(df['D'] == 0).combine_first(df['C'])
df.loc[:, 'F'] = me.groupby(['A', 'A_group'])['E'].cumsum()
```

Thanks to Scott Boston for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
grp = (df['D'] != 0).cumsum()
df['D_new'] = df['D'].mask(df['D'] == 0).combine_first(df['C']).groupby(grp).cumsum()
df
```

Output:

```
        A  B       C       D   D_new
75472  d1  x   -36.0     0.0   -36.0
75555  d2  x   -38.0     0.0   -74.0
75638  d3  x   -18.0     0.0   -92.0
75721  d4  x   -18.0  1836.0  1836.0
75804  d5  x  1151.0     0.0  2987.0
75887  d6  x   734.0     0.0  3721.0
75970  d7  x  -723.0     0.0  2998.0
```

#### Details:

Create grps to help cumsum. Each group is defined the the appears of a value in 'D' hence you stop cumsum before and pick that value of D and continue cumsum until the next value of 'D'

```
grp = (df['D'] != 0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
        A  B       C       D   D_new  grp
75472  d1  x   -36.0     0.0   -36.0    0
75555  d2  x   -38.0     0.0   -74.0    0
75638  d3  x   -18.0     0.0   -92.0    0
75721  d4  x   -18.0  1836.0  1836.0    1
75804  d5  x  1151.0     0.0  2987.0    1
75887  d6  x   734.0     0.0  3721.0    1
75970  d7  x  -723.0     0.0  2998.0    1
```

Now, Let's create new column combining 'C' and 'D' when D has a nonzero number

```
df['newCD'] = df['D'].mask(df['D'] == 0).combine_first(df['C'])
```

Output:

```
        A  B       C       D   D_new  grp   newCD
75472  d1  x   -36.0     0.0   -36.0    0   -36.0
75555  d2  x   -38.0     0.0   -74.0    0   -38.0
75638  d3  x   -18.0     0.0   -92.0    0   -18.0
75721  d4  x   -18.0  1836.0  1836.0    1  1836.0
75804  d5  x  1151.0     0.0  2987.0    1  1151.0
75887  d6  x   734.0     0.0  3721.0    1   734.0
75970  d7  x  -723.0     0.0  2998.0    1  -723.0
```

And, lastly, groupby 'grp' and `cumsum` newCD:

```
df['D_new_Details'] = df.groupby('grp')['newCD'].cumsum()
```

Output:

```
        A  B       C       D   D_new  grp   newCD  D_new_Details
75472  d1  x   -36.0     0.0   -36.0    0   -36.0          -36.0
75555  d2  x   -38.0     0.0   -74.0    0   -38.0          -74.0
75638  d3  x   -18.0     0.0   -92.0    0   -18.0          -92.0
75721  d4  x   -18.0  1836.0  1836.0    1  1836.0         1836.0
75804  d5  x  1151.0     0.0  2987.0    1  1151.0         2987.0
75887  d6  x   734.0     0.0  3721.0    1   734.0         3721.0
75970  d7  x  -723.0     0.0  2998.0    1  -723.0         2998.0
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Is there a way to generalize it to a group of A, B? Also - is there good docs on this? Some of these one liners in Pandas are like wizardry to me even after reading the documentation.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Nope, I had a very [similar problem to this using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47796227/6361531) a while back.  I use that SQL logic to write a pandas solution and added that algorithm to my toolbox.

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r I added some details to the solution hope it helps.

Comment: No as in no way to generalize it to a group of A, B? Your explanation is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: @gr1zzlybe4r Oh.. I am sure we can add A and B to the groupings.  I was stating no to an documentation on this particular algorithm.  At least, I don't know of any.  You just need to modify the `grp` statement to create your desired groups with A and B.

Comment: Yeah so to add A and B I think it's

`grp = df.groupby(['A', 'B', df['D'] > 0]).cumsum()
df['step1'].mask(df['step1'] == 0).combine_first(df['receipts_adjustments_sales']).groupby(grp).cumsum()`
?

Comment: Grouping is a little bit tougher, but I will get it and post it in my question once I figure it out

Comment: Updated my question with the group generalization

Answer (score 1):

Another, similar to Scott's answer:

```
groups = df['D'].ne(0).cumsum()
df['new'] = (df['C'].where(df['D'].eq(0), df['D'])
     .groupby(groups)
     .cumsum()
)
```

Comment: It would help if you explained this a logic in steps.

Comment: @ScottBoston That would copy what you wrote :-)